# Serve data from different locations depending on a query parameter

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, querystring

I would like to serve data on one and the same host from different directories depending on a query parameter using Nginx.

For example `https://foo.bar/index.html` should be served from `/var/www/foo` and `https://foo.bar/index.html?baz=quux` from `/var/www/bar`.

I've tried to change the server `root` conditionally, but it turns out it's not supported.

```
root /var/www/foo;    
if ($args ~ baz=quux) {
    # this is not gonna work but that is what is needed
    # root /var/www/bar;
}
```

Comment: That sounds like you're looking to use the [http rewrite module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) to `rewrite` certain requests...

Comment: Update should work. Though I would use `$arg_baz = quux`

Comment: @AlexeyTen yes actually it works. And thanks for pointing out to `$arg_baz`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the most elegant way to solve the problem, but using a variable in `root` directive works as expected.

```
set $env 'foo';
if ($arg_baz=quux) {
    set $env 'bar';
}
root /var/www/$env;
```